# Converting .tsv to .meg for visualization

Tags: format-conversion, k-mer, megax

This is an add-on to the previous question I asked [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/22005/process-gets-killed-before-completing/22006?noredirect=1#comment34017_22006).

I was able to deploy a "chunking" strategy to my kmer matrix and was able to get a file with the distance measurements! From what I could tell by using the `head` command was that the data looks like what it did before when I was using this approach on a smaller dataset so now I'm going to use this data to generate a tree using MEGAX.

Normally when I'd convert the `tsv` file to a `meg` file I'd manually add in the meg headers/requirements for conversion. However, I can't open the distance `tsv` file (its ~23 GB) to make these changes.

Is there an easy solution to this problem? How do you convert a `tsv` file to a `meg` file without opening the file?

EDIT:

For more context here is the format for each file.

Currently, my `tsv` file looks like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... 178
1 0 # # # # # # # # #  ... #
2 # 0 # # # # # # # #  ... #
3 # # 0 # # # # # # #  ... #
4 # # # 0 # # # # # #  ... #
5 # # # # 0 # # # # #  ... #
6 # # # # # 0 # # # #  ... #
7 # # # # # # 0 # # #  ... #
8 # # # # # # # 0 # #  ... #
9 # # # # # # # # 0 #  ... #
10 # # # # # # # # # 0 ... #
...
178 # # # # # # # # # #  ... 0
```

This is a jaccard distance matrix of 178 samples. The `#` represent the distance values for each sample compared to the other. I was able to calcualte the distance using pandas and scipy: `matrix = pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(data, 'jaccard')))`

And I would like it to look like this:

```
#mega
TITLE: Jaccard distance of 178 samples

sample_1
sample_2
sample_3
...
sample_178

distance_1
distance_1 distance_2
distance_1 distance_2 distance_3
distance_1 distance_2 distance_3 distance_4
...
distance_1 distance_2 distance_3 distance_4...distance_178
```

Comment: I added some extra information to give more context to this issue! Let me know if you'd like me to clarify something further or if you'd like more information. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Thanks @rimo .. okay this ain't the data set I imagined. I'll need to reproduce it. Are you using SciPy, i.e. where is the pdist() method coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Note, its a while since I've used `scipy` and I don't fancy loading an deleting for this test ... so in the absence of `pdist()` the solution would be ...

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

data = [[1,2,3],[0,5,6],[7,0,9],[10,11,0]]
arr = np.tril([data]).astype('float')
arr[arr == 0] = 'nan' 
arr = np.where(np.isnan(arr), '', arr)
columns = ['a','b','c', 'd']
file = Path('/Volumes/Data2/test/test1.meg')
if file.is_file():
    file.unlink()
with open(file, 'a') as fout:
    fout.write("#MEGA\n")
    for col in columns:
        fout.write(col + "\n")
    fout.write("\n0\n")
    np.savetxt(fout, arr.reshape(3,-1), fmt='%s')
```

**output**

```
#MEGA
a
b
c
d

0
1.0 0.0
5.0 7.0 0.0
9.0 10.0 11.0 0.0
```

That works. Keep in mind where it says `arr.reshape(3,-1)` the `3` should be the number of columns -1 in your matrix: **in your case this appears to be 177 (178 - 1)**.

The gist is to use `np.tril`, which doesn't exists in `pandas`. Hence don't use `pandas`.

At a guess with `scipy` then it would be ...

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from scipy import pdist

tmp = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]

data = pdist(tmp, 'jaccard')
arr = np.tril([data]).astype('float')
arr[arr == 0] = 'nan' 
arr = np.where(np.isnan(arr), '', arr)
columns = ['a','b','c', 'd']
file =Path('/Volumes/Data2/test/test1.meg')
if file.is_file():
    file.unlink()
with open(file, 'a') as fout:
    fout.write("#MEGA\n")
    for col in columns:
        fout.write(col + "\n")
    fout.write("\n0\n")
    np.savetxt(fout, arr.reshape(3,-1), fmt='%s')
```

You might need a quick `perl -p -i -e 's/[" "]+/ /g' test1.meg` or even `perl -p -i -e 's/[" "]+/\t/g' test1.meg` to set the file for MEGA. I dunno why but `\s` or `" "` in the transform part of perl pie isn't working for me.